# Select all checkboxes for each dynamic tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have more than one table. The table and rows are generated from the database. Each table on the top i got a checkbox, if i click only that particular table checkboxes needs to be checked. Like wise i got more tables and the check all should work independently for each tables. Here i have put the html for 2 tables.

My table structure is below:

```
<table width="800" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="inlineTable" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#000000">
<tr><td colspan="5" align="center" width="800"><strong>Haweye International&nbsp;(USD)</strong></td></tr>
<tr>
                <th>Sl No</th>
                <th width=130>Tender Description</th>
                <th>Main</th>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="selecctall"/></th>
                <th title="Selected to Quotation">S2Q</th>
                </tr>
        <tr align='center'><td>1</td><td width='140'>Silicon Free Tape </td><td></td><td><div class='list-item'><input class='checkbox1' type='checkbox' name='member[1]' value='53'></div></td><td title='Selected to Quotation' class="dark"><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="comparitive[]" value="53"  checked='checked' /></td>
</tr><tr align='center'><td>2</td><td width='140'>UV Sensitive Tape</td><td></td><td><div class='list-item'><input class='checkbox1' type='checkbox' name='member[2]' value='54'></div></td><td title='Selected to Quotation' class="dark"><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="comparitive[]" value="54"  checked='checked' /></td>
</tr></table>

<table width="800" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="inlineTable" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#000000">
<tr><td colspan="6" align="center" width="800"><strong>Trend Zone limited&nbsp;(USD)</strong></td></tr>
<tr>
                <th>Sl No</th>
                <th width=130>Tender Description</th>
                <th>Tech %</th>
                <th>Main</th>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="selecctall"/></th>
                <th title="Selected to Quotation">S2Q</th>
                </tr>
        <tr align='center'><td>1</td><td width='140'>Silicon Free Tape </td><td></td><td></td><td><div class='list-item'><input class='checkbox1' type='checkbox' name='member[3]' value='63'></div></td><td title='Selected to Quotation' class="dark"><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="comparitive[]" value="63" /></td>
</tr><tr align='center'><td>2</td><td width='140'>UV Sensitive Tape</td><td></td><td></td><td><div class='list-item'><input class='checkbox1' type='checkbox' name='member[4]' value='64'></div></td><td title='Selected to Quotation' class="dark"><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="comparitive[]" value="64" /></td>
</tr></table>
```

The jquery is below:

```
$('.selectAll').click(function(e){
  var tr= $(e.target).closest('tr');
  $('td input:checkbox',tr).prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

Comment: I don't see any checkbox at the top http://imgur.com/l7zZbCc

Comment: Use `class` instead of `id`..`id` must be unique..

Comment: @Illamerr. After Main you a see a checkbox in the header.. Its the checkall checkbox.

Comment: The rows are created dynamically with PHP. That's why iam not sure how to create dynamic ids.. That's why i opted for table.

Comment: Is it possible with table. That when i check the checkall box of the first table it should check all of that particular table only and like wise other tables.. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `id` attributes should be unique. Use class instead
2. Use `.not()` to exclude current element.
3. Use `:checkbox` selector to select only `type= 'checkbox'` elements

```js
$('.selectAll').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('table').find('.list-item :checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="800" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="inlineTable" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#000000">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" align="center" width="800"><strong>Haweye International&nbsp;(USD)</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sl No</th>
    <th width=130>Tender Description</th>
    <th>Main</th>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll" />
    </th>
    <th title="Selected to Quotation">S2Q</th>
  </tr>
  <tr align='center'>
    <td>1</td>
    <td width='140'>Silicon Free Tape</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class='list-item'>
        <input class='checkbox1' type='checkbox' name='member[1]' value='53'>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td title='Selected to Quotation' class="dark">
      <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="comparitive[]" value="53" checked='checked' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr align='center'>
    <td>2</td>
    <td width='140'>UV Sensitive Tape</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class='list-item'>
        <input class='checkbox1' type='checkbox' name='member[2]' value='54'>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td title='Selected to Quotation' class="dark">
      <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="comparitive[]" value="54" checked='checked' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table width="800" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="inlineTable" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#000000">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6" align="center" width="800"><strong>Trend Zone limited&nbsp;(USD)</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sl No</th>
    <th width=130>Tender Description</th>
    <th>Tech %</th>
    <th>Main</th>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll" />
    </th>
    <th title="Selected to Quotation">S2Q</th>
  </tr>
  <tr align='center'>
    <td>1</td>
    <td width='140'>Silicon Free Tape</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class='list-item'>
        <input class='checkbox1' type='checkbox' name='member[3]' value='63'>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td title='Selected to Quotation' class="dark">
      <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="comparitive[]" value="63" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr align='center'>
    <td>2</td>
    <td width='140'>UV Sensitive Tape</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class='list-item'>
        <input class='checkbox1' type='checkbox' name='member[4]' value='64'>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td title='Selected to Quotation' class="dark">
      <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="comparitive[]" value="64" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A small doubt. Do u know PHP also. I got a doubt with related to php and jquery stuff. i already asked that as a question, but not much help received..

Answer (score 1):

Give that checkbox class name `class="selectAll"` for each main checkbox and JS would be like following :

```
// just in case
// use event delegation here to ensure appended elements
// were bound to this handler
// you can replace `document` with the placeholder
// that dynamic elements inserted with
$(document).on('click','.selectAll', function(e){
  var table= $( this ).closest('table');
  table.find(':checkbox').not( this ).prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/3L7pazmm/)